# Get data from string instead of text for random option

Tags: java, android

I have a question regarding using strings instead of just text. I would like to use strings instead of text, to make translation easier. So when I use:

```java
taken f02 = new taken("tegd")
```

its working but when i implement the code:

```java
taken f01 = new taken(getString(R.string.proberen));
```

the app keeps closing without an error message. Someone who has experience with this and can help me solve the problem?:)

```java
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button mbutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.taken);
        mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.taken_button);
        showRandom();
        mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showRandom();
            }
        });
        }
        public void showRandom(){
            shuffletaken();
            mTextView.setText(TakenArray[3].getMtaken());
        }
    taken f01 = new taken(getString(R.string.proberen));
    taken f02 = new taken("tegd");
    taken f03 = new taken("test");
    taken f04 = new taken("xcz");
    taken f05 = new taken("dvg");
    
    taken [] TakenArray = new taken[]{
            f01,f02,f03,f04,f05};
        public void shuffletaken() {
                Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(TakenArray));
        }
    }
}

public class taken {
    private String mtaken;

    public taken(String mtaken){
        this.mtaken = mtaken;
    }

    public String getMtaken(){
        return mtaken;
    }
}
```

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">challenges</string>

    <string name="test">test</string>
    <string name="a">a</string>
    <string name="b">b</string>
    <string name="ct">c</string>
    <string name="d">d</string>
    <string name="proberen">test</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used getString() methode in class declaration ,so the activity not attached to the context yet. you must use getString() in or after onCreate() method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!, will check in the coming days if i can fix it!